# Apply an AND filter on search results with Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a django application where I maintain a list of products. Each product has a number of "categorizations" attached to it. I want to search the table of product and apply filters to that search, so that with each added filter, there are less and less products returned.

The categorizations have a relationship to product. They way they are attached to products is a bit complicated, but here is the gist of it:

```
class ProductCategorization(Categorization):
  """
  A categorization value selected for a specific `Product`
  """
  value = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategorizationValue, related_name="categorizations",   on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="categorizations", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductCategorizationValue(CategorizationValue):
  value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So you could imagine that you would search for all products that have a categorization with value "SHOES" as follows:

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(categorizations__value__value="SHOES"))
```

Now this is all fine. However, now I want to apply a second filter, so that I only get a list of products that are SHOES and BLUE. I have tried variations of the following but I keep getting an empty list instead of relevant products:

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(categorizations__value__value="SHOES") & Q(categorizations__value__value="BLUE"))
```

I know there is something strange going on behind the scenes when the SQL query is built, I just can't figure out how to structure my Django code.

**----- EDIT**

There are two things that I am concerned about: 1. performance - I want this all to be basically converted to a single Postgres query if possible, 2. I also need to apply other stuff to the filter, such as distance from a point (using GeoDjango) and a limit for paging. The full query is something like

```
Product.objects.filter(fullSearchCondition).distinct().annotate(distance=DistanceFunction("owner__currentLocation__virtualLocation__coordinates", searchOriginPoint)).order_by("distance", "-dateCreated")[:MAX_RESULTS]
```

where `fullSearchCondition` is what I am trying to build with these multiple filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter *twice* to use two JOINs instead of the single one you use here:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    categorizations__value__value='SHOES'
).filter(
    categorizations__value__value='BLUE'
)
```

for a (small) list of filters, you can use:

```
filters = ['SHOES', 'BLUE']

qs = Product.objects.all()
for item in filters:
    qs = qs.filter(categorizations__value__value=item)
```

But from the moment the number of filters grows a bit large (four or more), this will likely make the query slow.

You can also make one `JOIN`, and count the number of matching filters:

```
from django.db.models import Count

filters = ['SHOES', 'BLUE']
filter_set = set(filters)

Product.objects.filter(
    categorizations__value__value__in=filter_set
).annotate(
    nfilter=Count('categorizations')
).filter(
    nfilter=len(filter_set)
)
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this dynamically by the way? So I don't know upfront how many of these filters I will have. I am trying to build the query as user presses a button, submitting their filters. So I guess - is there an efficient way of adding these filters in a for loop through filter values for example?

Comment: @Elendurwen: you can use looping, but if there are a lot of filters, you better count the number of valyues.

Comment: sorry could you please explain that a little bit? I have edited my original question to give a bit more background.

Comment: Thaks a lot for your help !